# Why PHPStorm doesn't give me any suggestion?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm currently moving to this IDE for PHP because I really like some phpstorm features but I'm having problems.

Let's write some code:

index.php:

```
require('app/registry/registry.class.php');
require('app/config.php');
$registry = new Registry();

$registry->createAndStoreObject('authentication', 'auth'); 
// $registry->getObject('auth')-> THE PROBLEM COMES HERE, the ide doesn't give me any suggestion and there are some.
$registry->getObject('auth')->checkForAuthentication(); // This is working, checkForAuthentication() should be a suggestion.
```

authentication.class.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Description:..
 * @author:..
 * Authenticate Class.
*/
require_once('template.class.php');
class Authentication {

    private $registry; // Registry Object
    private $loggedIn; // Boolean
    private $justProcessed; // Boolean
    private $user; // User Object
    private $loginFailureReason; // String. Toma valor en caso de que no sea posible el logeo.


    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->loggedIn = false;
    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @internal param $null
     * @return void ?
     */
    public function checkForAuthentication()
    {
        //..
    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @param int $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function sessionAuthenticate($id)
    {
          //....
    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @param String $e The user.
     * @param String $p The password.
     * @return void
     */
    private function postAuthenticate($e, $p)
    {
        /..
    }

}
?>
```

I've already inspect the code if that's worth something. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance guys!!

EDIT:

**Not working**

[image: Not working]

**Working**

[image: Working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "tell" IDE what is the type of variabe. Change

```
$registry->getObject('auth')->checkForAuthentication();
```

to

```
/** @var Authentication $auth */   
$auth = $registry->getObject('auth');
$auth->checkForAuthentication();
```

This is quit normal, because object is "generated" dynamically. If you used standard constructor, PhpStorm would have suggested auto-completion automatically.

There is an example:

### [image]

Comment: Not working :( I think i've already tried this but thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Have you provided full PHP files or just fragments?

Comment: It does not work, because PhpStorm does not know what type of object gets out of Registry::getObject()